# How do I specify parameters to Oauth providers using oauth2 for Python?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

[Documentation for the Python `oath2` library](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/) offers a very simple example of how to authenticate to Twitter:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

# Create your consumer with the proper key/secret.
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="your-twitter-consumer-key", 
    secret="your-twitter-consumer-secret")

# Request token URL for Twitter.
request_token_url = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

# Create our client.
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# The OAuth Client request works just like httplib2 for the most part.
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
print resp
print content
```

However, how do I specify extra parameters? For instance, Facebook requires the "scope" parameter to request such data as email addresses. Furthermore, are there examples that use other providers than Twitter such as Facebook or Google OAuth2?

Answer (score 1):

by looking at the code of `oath2` lib, the `client.request()` has a place for additional parameters:

```
def request(self, uri, method="GET", body='', headers=None, 
        redirections=httplib2.DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS, connection_type=None):

        ...

        if is_form_encoded and body:
            parameters = parse_qs(body)
        else:
            parameters = None
```

It seems the `body` argument will be parsed into parameters. I copy the following fb oauth request sample from the fb dev site. I think adding the part after `?`, which includes the scope parameter, as `body` argument should be working.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
   &state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. Just curious, how did find the code for oauth2? I was clicking through folders on https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2 but I couldn't find the source code above.

Comment: @JohnHoffman [oauth2/__init__.py](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py) file; most of the api wrappers I played with put major code in this file:)

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be a list of tuples, for example:

```
[("language","pt")]
```